# Match Users skills

Tags: comments

I am designing a website and there are two users 1:users and 2:company. I want two field in different account need to match with each other. If users provide specific SKILLs and company requires specific SKILLS person then matching skills show result to company and a user.
Please please help me if any confusion ask me

Comment: Its like matchmaking , company should see the same skills users and users should see same company. If user choose skills and same skills a company required for specific project then it need to match with each other and show the result on both side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one approach to creating different user accounts, it depends on your particular needs. Maybe [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and [Multiple Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_registration) would do.

Create a Taxonomy Vocabulary called `Skills` with terms inside for each of the skills. Then create an Entity reference field on User account settings referencing that Vocabulary. This means that each user and each company will be able to choose skills on their edit profile pages.

Then with Views you can create blocks listing users, and use Contextual filters to filter out only users that have the same skills chosen, as those selected on the page where the block is displayed. When you visit a Company page, this page will have some skills chosen, and a block there will be showing all users that have ticked the same skills.

The same can be created to be shown on User profiles, a Block displaying only Companies, but filtered out to only those companies that have the same skills selected as that user.

This is the concept of how to do it. Details are out of scope of answering it here (you can find other questions where this was solved for related content through taxonomy).

You have to be careful depending on whether you allow for one, or multiple skills to be chosen (settings are a bit different).

Emails can be sent to users (with Rules module) when a new company matching their skills is posted. The same for companies, when a new user with their skills is created.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need two different user role, can be named as `Company` and `Expert`.

Then you will need two content types, lets call them `Job-position` and `Job-appliance` which can be created by Companies and Experts respectively (You can set permissions on that).

In next Step you will need two [view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) blocks, you can call them `proper jobs` and `proper experts`, the first block should be viewed in a content of type 'Job-appliance' so when a user navigate to an 'job appliance' will see a list of proper job positions for that. Almost same functionality should be provided for other view as well.

These views can be modified in a manner which takes argument from context, and filter out needed results.

for ease of use with views in this situation I recommend usage of [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module, so you can pass arguments easier.

Also if you need different registration fields for each user role, I suggest [Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile) module (for Drupal 8, in case of using drupal 7 you can use [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module)